# Find the pollution percentage of a dataset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, signal-processing, noise

I think this is a simple question but I really doubt what should I consider. In a signal for example with 20000 data, if I know 4000 of data are spikes, how should I compute the pollution percentage? something like:

```
x = 4000 / 20000 * 100
y = 4000 / (20000 - 4000) * 100
```

or anything else? the true pollution percentage is `noises / all` or `noise / valid_data` ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming half of the data is noise then I would certainly expect a $50$% pollution (i.e. $x$) rather than $100$% (i.e. $y$).

Note also that $y$ is unbounded, do you really want pollution to go to infinity when all data is corrupted ?

Since your wording is "pollution **percentage**" only $x$ fits the range $0..100$.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I wasn't thinking in the right way at all.